# Alternative to expo-file-system getInfoAsync

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have used expo in my react native project but I'm now trying to remove it. I'm looking at react-native-fs as a replacement for expo-file-system.

Is there an analog for the **FileSystem.getInfoAsync** method in react-native-fs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing that looks like the getAsyncInfo is the `stat` function. Though, of course you'll have to change the result you were getting from getInfoAsync.